# label property is nil,container view

Tags: objective-c, xcode, properties, uilabel, ioc-container

Situation:

3 view controllers, white is main, red and blue are embedded (container view controllers)
I select something in red,it switches to blue,I swipe the blue - it goes back and I want to change text in the label to some custom text

Sequence:[image][image][image]

So I use delegation and it also works.But when I try to set label's text property(in the method that confirms my protocol) via `self.thisLabel.text` NSLog says this label is nil, although I have an outlet. If I use something like `[self.view viewWithTag:tag]` NSLog shows that label is there but I can't set the text, it stays the same.

#### code in white:

header

```
@interface ContactsViewController : UIViewController <BlueViewControllerDelegate>
```

implementation

```
- (void)adjustLabel:(NSString *)string{
    NSLog(@"i am here baby %@",self.thisLabel);
    [[self.view viewWithTag:57] setValue:string forKey:@"text"];
}
```

#### code in blue:

header:

```
@protocol BlueViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
    -(void)adjustLabel:(NSString*)string;
@end
```

and:

```
@property id<ViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

implementation

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIStoryboard *sB = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    WhiteViewController *WhiteVc = [sB instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"whiteID"];
    self.delegate = WhiteVc;
}

-(void)willMoveToParentViewController:(UIViewController *)parent{
    [self.delegate adjustLabel:@"some custom text"];
}

-(IBAction)swipePerformed:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)sender{
    [self willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self removeFromParentViewController];
}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your VC hierarchy correctly, the `WhiteViewController` is the parent of `BlueViewController`, so you shouldn't instantiate a new one from the storyboard in `viewDidLoad` but do instead:

```
WhiteViewController *whiteVc = (WhiteViewController*)self.parentViewController;
self.delegate = whiteVC;
```

Also, I don't find overriding `willMoveToParentViewController` particularly useful. You could put your delegate call to your swipe action.

Comment: the white view controller is independent.Instead there are relationships between red(container view controller) and blue(its child)

Comment: @efimovD Is the white VC the root(initial) view controller of your app?

Comment: @efimovD ok, so you can get it by: `WhiteViewController *whiteVC =(WhiteViewController *)[[(YourAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate] window] rootViewController]`

Comment: 100% right,the problem was that I instantiated new white controller every time but I needed a reference to an existing white controller.Thank you very very much!